# Understanding syntax of closure with no return type

Tags: swift, closures, conditional-binding

I am getting into swift for the first time here and I have stumbled across a closure statement that doesn't make a whole lot sense to me based off of my current understanding of how closures are written. This is really a two-part question because I also don't quite grasp the intention/interpretation behind the conditional binding with this closure.

The chunk of code I am thrown by is this:

```
 FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) {
    (user, error) in if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }
}
```

My understanding is that the closure needs specify a return type based off of the docs definition `(something1, something2) -> ()` so from the bit of code above, does that just mean that swift can infer a void return by not including the `-> ()`?

My assumption is that the conditional binding statement just says 'if an error arg is passed into this closure, then print the error?

Please use as much detail as possible in your explanation as possible so I can further my understanding. Cheers!

Comment: What is the context of the code you've posted? Is it the contents of a closure? (inside a set of `{}`?)

Comment: @MattSanford I think you're still missing a closing `}`

Comment: You are correct @Alexander

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following are all equivalent

```
func foo1() -> () { }
func foo2() -> () { return () }
func foo3() -> () { return Void() }
func foo4() -> () { return }

func foo5() -> Void { }
func foo6() -> Void { return () }
func foo7() -> Void { return Void() }
func foo8() -> Void { return }

func foo9() { }
func foo10() { return () }
func foo11() { return Void() }
func foo12() { return }

print(type(of: foo1))  // (()) -> ()
// ...
print(type(of: foo5))  // (()) -> ()
// ...
print(type(of: foo9))  // (()) -> ()
// ...
```

If no return *type* is supplied to a function(/closure), then the empty tuple *type* (which is typealiased by `Void`) is inferred. We may, however, explicitly supply this return *type*, either as `()` (the *type*), or `Void`. From [the language guide - functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html):

> **Functions Without Return Values**
>
> Functions are not required to define a return type. ...
>
> ...
>
> Strictly speaking, this version of the `greet(person:)` function does
>   still return a value, even though no return value is defined.
>   Functions *without a defined return type return a special value of
>   type `Void`*. This is simply an empty tuple, which is written as `()`.

Conversely, if no `return` is given at the end of a function block, it will be the same as explicitly returning an *instance* of the empty tuple, namely `()` (the *value*). This may also be written simply as `return`.

Comment: Wow I had no idea that there were so many ways to write the same thing. That is incredibly helpful

Comment: @jtbandes it does look a bit weird, but I believe it follows the general convention: the type annotation of arguments in the combined type annotation of a closure (arguments and return type) are enclosed by parenthesis, which is even required e.g. when explicitly including type annotation in the body of a closure (e.g. `{ (arg: Int) -> Int in 2*arg }`). Or maybe you refer to another weirdness, and I missed the point? Thanks for feedback!

Comment: My point is that you could say `foo1` takes *no* arguments, so I would expect `() -> ()`, but it's printed as if it takes a single argument of type `()`. These are often interchangeable. Probably related to the work being done for https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0110-distingish-single-tuple-arg.md

Comment: @jtbandes ah, I see, and I agree. It seems as if the current type annotation explicitly chooses to treat the no-argument case as an explicit single empty-tuple argument. I guess this could be seen as somewhat of a discrepancy, as e.g. `let closure1: () -> Int = { ... }` is allowed, whereas `let closure2: Int -> Int = { ... }` is not (since the type of `closure` is presented as `(()) -> Int`, then we should be required to enclose `()` by paranthesis when we declare, but this would be madness, so a better approach would be to let the special void-argument case simply have type `() -> ...`).

Comment: @MattSanford happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

`()` is the empty tuple. `Void` in Swift is just a type alias to `()`. If a function or closure doesn't specify a return type, then `()` is assumed.

To avoid confusion, the `(user, error) in` should be on its own line:

```
 FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { user, error in
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }
 }
```

I'd suggest using a `guard` statement to enforce an early return:

```
 FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { user, error in
    guard error == nil else {
        print(error!.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

     // There's no error, carry on...
 }
```

Comment: further down in that function I have other things going on so I wanted to end the execution if in fact there was an error present. What about the `(user, error) in` being on its on line would cause confusion? (My second part of the original question)